# RDieHarder package: installations error

Tags: r

I have a problem with installing **RDieHarder** package for R ver. 3.3. on Windows 10.
I got an error:

```
 Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Student/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘RDieHarder’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘RDieHarder’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RDieHarder_0.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 390268 bytes (381 KB)
downloaded 381 KB

* installing *source* package 'RDieHarder' ...
** pakiet 'RDieHarder' został pomyślnie rozpakowany oraz sumy MD5 zostały sprawdzone

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c add_ui_rngs.c -o add_ui_rngs.o
In file included from add_ui_rngs.c:7:0:
dieharder.h:24:25: fatal error: gsl/gsl_rng.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [add_ui_rngs.o] Error 1
Ostrzeżenie: uruchomione polecenie 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="RDieHarder.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="add_ui_rngs.o choose_rng.o dieharder.o dieharder_exit.o help.o list_rand.o list_rngs.o list_tests.o output.o output_rnds.o parsecl.o rng_empty_random.o run_all_tests.o run_test.o startup.o time_rng.o user_template.o"' otrzymało status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RDieHarder'
* removing 'C:/Users/Student/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RDieHarder'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Student\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1UTXT/downloaded_packages/RDieHarder_0.1.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RDieHarder’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1UTXT\downloaded_packages’
```

I really don't know what's the problem. I did it many times. But for this package standard installation doesnt't work. I did it this way:

```
install.packages("RDieHarder")
```

I also tried to install it from download file, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the GSL library is not installed, which according to the [description on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RDieHarder/index.html) is required for the RDieHarder package:

> SystemRequirements:   DieHarder library (>= 3.31.1) from http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php, **GNU GSL for the GSL random-number generators**

Installing the [GSL library](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm) should remove that error.

Comment: I had  **gsl** already installed .

Updating didn't solve this problem

Comment: The decisive error is `#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h> : No such file or directory.` If GSL is really installed, the system doesn't seem to be able find it. Check if it is included in the PATH.

Comment: Perhaps the location of gsl must be explicitly specified in the include directories of the configure script, as hinted by Sixiang.Hu

Comment: I thought that it is about R library gsl, but now I understand that it is something else... But how to install it on Windows 10? I tried to download it from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm but I don't know which files I need, where they should be on my Windows, and if I have to install them or only unpack

Comment: I am working almost exclusively on linux and I don't know about the details concerning the installation of GSL on windows. I was expecting that the instructions in the link that I posted would help. In any case it appears that your question has evolved from "how to install RDieHarder" to "how to install the GSL library on windows 10". I suggest that you ask that specific question in a separate post in order to increase the chances to obtain a helpful answer. Perhaps this one can be closed now?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the warning message, you may need to manually specify the location of the DieHarder software using `configure.args` in `install.packages`

More info please check:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/having-trouble-installing-RDieHarder-td4670295.html

**[EDIT]**

Method 1:

As I don't have DieHard installed on my PC, the code below is just an example to show how to use `configure.args`:

From the folder where you have DieHard installed:

1. There must be a subfolder in which you can find .dll files, let's name the path as path1, and
2. another subfolder where you can find some .h files, let's name the path as path2.
3. In R you need something like:

   install.packages("RDieHarder",configure.args="--with-dieharder-include=path2 --with-dieharder-libdir=path1")

Method 2:

This method jumped into my mind while written the possible answer above.  After you installed `DieHard`, system environment variable `PATH` may have software location installed. But it may not include both path1 and path2 mentioned above. Try adding both path1 and path2 to the `PATH` environment variable and then:

```
install.packages("RDieHarder")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to specify this argument. I saw this page earlier and I don't know hot to use it

Comment: Do you have idea how to install DieHarder from http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php on my Windows 10? I tried, but it's difficult for me

Comment: From the link provided, it didn't provide a windows installer.  Looks like you don't have Dieharder installed which causes the issue, (RHertel is right on this.).  solutions are: 1. find alternative (another Dieharder on windows); 2. virtual machine on windows.

Comment: I tried installing it on linux mint, but I'm new to it and I don't have idea how to do it. I have R installed on linux

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of Linux and your question now has been changed to "how to install DieHarder on linux".  Suggest you raise a new question.